# Atmosphere framework - Is there any security concerns because of query string in request URI

Tags: security, query-string, atmosphere, querystringparameter, atmosphere.js

I am using Atmosphere framework for web socket communication in my application. The generated web socket URLs contains X-Atmosphere-tracking-id, X-Atmosphere-Framework, X-Atmosphere-Transport, X-atmo-protocol etc. parameters as query string like mentioned below

```
wss://localhost:8080/chat?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=3.0.0-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Heartbeat-Server=65&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true&uuId=cc610c86-37a2-75b4-fbfc-36a9cb8220cb&spring-security-redirect=%2Fchat%2Findex&Accept-Language=en
```

Is there any security issues can exists because of exposing X-Atmosphere-tracking-id, X-Atmosphere-Framework, X-Atmosphere-Transport, X-atmo-protocol etc. parameters as query string in URLs?

By using the browser devtools, we are able to see the complete URL with query string so